# Why is CSS style for table TD:last-of-type unwantedly triggered in IE depending on the TD's content?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm facing a display problem which happens only with IE.
I defined a class in CSS for "table with rounded corners" (means the TD at each of its corners, not all or random TD).
I defined a form, actually several small forms, with basic functions such as Delete or Modify the table entry.
The table and related included forms are built by PHP.

See screenshots (IE, FF, CR) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u60C.jpg

IE uses the CSS which is intended for the bottom-right table corner for each TD with a submit button, which is unintended. This seems to depend on the TD's content.

I already confirmed below :

- Firefox and Chrome work perfectly fine regardless of the TD's content, so I can say it is narrowed down to IE only.
- This unwanted behavior happens with attached HTML code, so I can say it is not a server-side issue.
- I already tried to put the  tag outside of the TD, it did not change the behavior.
- When the TD's content is just text (text), there is no problem.
- When the TD's content is either a button or input type submit ( or ), the issue happens.
- I can tell that this is below CSS line which is triggered unwantedly, because I changed the radius in this styling block only, to be sure :

  table.rounded   tbody tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type

Now I share relevant HTML and CSS codes.

HTML code :

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">             
    </head>

    <body>

        <section>
            <h1>Site Administration</h1>

            <h2>Classes' Schedule</h2>

<table class="rounded">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Monday</strong></td>
            <td>19:00 - 22:00</td>
            <td>Rugby</td>
            <td>teacher 1, teacher 2</td>
            <td><form method="post" action="admin.php">
            <button type="submit" name="class_to_delete" value="1">Delete</button>
            </form></td>
            <td><form method="post" action="admin.php">
            Modify</form></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Tuesday</strong></td>
            <td>19:00 - 22:00</td>
            <td>Soccer</td>
            <td>teacher 3, teacher 4</td>
            <td><form method="post" action="admin.php">
            <button type="submit" name="class_to_delete" value="2">Delete</button>
            </form></td>
            <td><form method="post" action="admin.php">
            Modify</form></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Friday</strong></td>
            <td>19:00 - 22:00</td>
            <td colspan=2>Description of regular events</td>
            <td><form method="post" action="admin.php">
            <button type="submit" name="class_to_delete" value="14">Delete</button>
            </form></td>
            <td><form method="post" action="admin.php">
            Modify</form></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <caption>List of Classes</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="centered">Day</th>
            <th class="centered">Hours</th>
            <th class="centered">Sport</th>
            <th class="centered">Teachers</th>
            <th>Del.</th>
            <th>Modif.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

        </section>

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS code :

```
table.rounded   thead th:first-of-type  { /* 10px 0 0 0 : Top Left, for table with min 2 columns */
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius:     10px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft:         10px; 
        border-top-left-radius:             10px;
        }

table.rounded   thead th:last-of-type  { /* 0 10px 0 0 : Top Right, for table with min 2 columns */
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius:    10px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright:        10px; 
        border-top-right-radius:            10px;
        }

table.rounded   tbody tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type  { /* 0 0 10px 0 : Bottom Right, for table with min 2 columns */
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright:     10px; 
        border-bottom-right-radius:         10px;
        }

table.rounded   tbody tr:last-of-type td:first-of-type { /* 0 0 0 10px : Bottom Left, for table with min 2 columns */
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:  10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:      10px; 
        border-bottom-left-radius:          10px;
        }

/* - borders */
table.rounded  {
        border-collapse: separate;
        }

table.rounded  tr {
        border: 0px;
        }

table.rounded   th, 
table.rounded   td {
        border-top:    1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-left:   0px;
        border-right:  1px solid black;
        }

table.rounded   th:first-of-type,
table.rounded   td:first-of-type {
        border-left:   1px solid black;
        }

table.rounded   tr:last-of-type td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }

table.rounded   td.afterrowspan {  /* follows in next tr, after the tr including the td which has rowspan defined */
        border-left:   0px;
        }

/* - corners [same as above] */

section table {
        float: center;

        max-width:  90%;

        margin-top:     10px;
        margin-bottom:  5px;
        margin-left:    auto; /* centers the table horizontally */
        margin-right:   auto; /* centers the table horizontally */

        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
        border-collapse: collapse; /* does not work with property Radius */
        border-spacing: 0px;
        }

section table th,
section table td {
        color:              #000000; /* Black */
        font-size: 16px;

        /* min-width: 150px; */

        margin: 5px 0px 3px 0px;
        padding-top:    4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        padding-left:   5px;
        padding-right:  5px;

        border: 1px solid black;
        -webkit-border-radius:  0px;/*Safari,Opera,Chrome*/ 
        -moz-border-radius:     0px; 
        border-radius:          0px;

        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: left;
        }
```

What I need your kind help for, is :

1. Understand the root cause of this unwanted behavior in IE
2. Find a hack or workaround for IE, using only HTML and CSS (no JS or any other addition).

Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: What does, tr>td:last-child do?

Comment: I tried with your suggestion as follows : https://imgur.com/a/0ABXy1H
- 1st image is with following selectors :
table.rounded  tbody tr > td:last-child
- 2nd image selectors :
table.rounded  tbody tr:last-of-type > td:last-child 
- 3rd image selectors :
table.rounded  tbody tr:last-of-type > td:last-of-type

Comment: So, tr:last-of-type > td:last-child  actually works. This answers for the workaround which is great, but I still don't understand why the td:last-of-type is triggered when not the last of type...

I will also cleanup the order in my HTML (i.e. in my PHP).